# How to use global variables in Flask app with multiple process enabled

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I have a Flask application has following app setup:

```
game_dict = load_game_dict()    
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=False, threaded=False, processes=3)
```

Here the game_dict is some meta data which load from db. we have a requirement to refresh this game_dict once a week, so I defined another GET method for admin to refresh it:

```
@app.route('/api/admin/reload/dict', methods=['GET'])
def api_admin_reload_dict():
    """ API for reloading game dict from database at runtime """
    global game_dict
    game_dict = load_game_dict()
```

I found it doesn't work, I debug and found the game_dict after this call still keep the initial value, I guess it is because I am using processes=3 here.

Did anyone have the idea about how to process in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Global variables are generally not a good idea for a multithreaded/processed application - but why not just restart the process(es) once a week?

Comment: Two processes will have different set of global variables. You can save value in a pickle file and update that pickle file on the get api call.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple processes will not have access to each others memory.

However, two processes can read data from a shared entity. Where an entity could be a database or object in memory or another process.

If game_dict doesn't hold much data you could hit your db before every request and reload the game_dict variable with the new data.

If hitting the database for all the game_dict data is slow then you could set a counter flag that updates whenever the game_dict metadata in the db is updated, and then compare the current process' counter to the db's counter and update the current process' game_dict variable if the counters differ.

Alternatively you could use Python's builtin [Multiprocessing Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.managers) object  for sharing state across processes by creating a separate server process that manages the shared state.